# Select Unique to get just months from dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in rails 5.

This works in the Sqlite query tool:

```
SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%m', date) FROM "dailylogs" ORDER BY "dailylogs"."created_at" DESC
```

But I am struggling to get something to work in my rails code, I have got to this:

```
@dailylog_months = Dailylog.select(strftime('%m', date)).distinct
```

But I get this error:

undefined local variable or method `date' for #

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

`@dailylog_months = Dailylog.select("strftime('%m', date)").distinct`

With the quotes around the select statement. To make it accessible from Ruby you probably need:

`@dailylog_months = Dailylog.select("strftime('%m', date) as month").distinct`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're referring `date` which is a part of `Dailylog`, so your query should be:

```
@dailylog_months = Dailylog.select(strftime('%m', :date)).distinct
```

Also, if you've multiple dates then you can do something like this:

```
@dailylog_months = Dailylog.select { |d| strftime('%m', d.date)}.distinct
```

Let me know if that solved your problem :)

Comment: Thanks,it has worked to the extent that it moved me on to another problem!!

Comment: @Simonp27 no problem, drop a message if you're still facing problems

Comment: @Simonp27 also, if this is the correct answer to your question then please mark it as such. So it will help people who stumble upon this page from some search page

Comment: Hi

both replies really helped to get to my final solution which was:

      @dailylog_months = Dailylog.select("date").group("strftime('%m', date)")

Using GROUP gave me all the fields to access in my results.

Thank you